# Determine clockwise vertexes that make up a face for a cube

Tags: python, geometry, blender, algebra

the title may seem a bit confusing however here is the scenario. I am writing a simple exporter in blender and I have the following information, I am trying to export a cube, I have the faces and the edges that make up the faces, along with which vertex makes up the edge. I am trying to assign the vertices in a clockwise order to create a cube. Basically, by clockwise I mean the top and bottom vertices go in the pattern of the image attached. 
[image]

For example, when grabbing all of the faces of the cube and checking which edges make up the face than what vertices make up that face, I am given the following with each parentheses being an edge and the two vertices that make it:

```
face 1 - (0, 1) (1, 2) (2, 3) (0, 3)
face 2 - 4, 7) (6, 7) (5, 6) (4, 5)
face 3 - (0, 4) (4, 5) (1, 5) (0, 1)
face 4 - (1, 5) (5, 6) (2, 6) (1, 2)
face 5 - (2, 6) (6, 7) (3, 7) (2, 3)
face 6 - (0, 4) (0, 3) (3, 7) (4, 7)
```

Basically the goal is to have 6 lines of vertices in order to create the cube, for example 0, 1, 2, 3 would create the top of the cube 4, 5, 6, 7 would create the bottom. However, I need the order to be in a clockwise format starting from top left of the side pretty much, which is where I am stuck. Would anyone be able to explain to me how I can do this or give an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as "clockwise" in 3D space, since you can look at the plane figure from either side. In your drawings, do you mean in both cases that the body of the cube is "behind" the square we are viewing, i.e. farther from me than the plane of my monitor is? In other words, are we viewing the top and bottom faces from outside the cube?

Comment: My drawing may not have been correct. I'm basically picking any point on the cube (top left for example) and setting it to vertex 0. From there I begin labeling the cube in the order above. It's not that it has to be that specific point, it's just the point I chose for that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am not sure, but below is some python code that I think is what you're looking for. Given the edges, it tries to orient all the faces in a "consistent" way. Note that the orientation of a given face is such that if you placed the cube so that only that face is visible, then the vertices are listed in clockwise order.

```
FACE_EDGES = [
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 3)],
    [(4, 7), (6, 7), (5, 6), (4, 5)],
    [(0, 4), (4, 5), (1, 5), (0, 1)],
    [(1, 5), (5, 6), (2, 6), (1, 2)],
    [(2, 6), (6, 7), (3, 7), (2, 3)],
    [(0, 4), (0, 3), (3, 7), (4, 7)]
]

# gets vertices of a face, but may be "clockwise" or                                                                                                                 
# "counterclockwise"                                                                                                                                                 
def get_vertices_from_edges(edges):
    verts = [edges[0][0]]
    for i in range(3):
        for a, b in edges:
            if a == verts[-1] and b not in verts:
                verts.append(b)
                break
            if b == verts[-1] and a not in verts:
                verts.append(a)
                break
    return verts

def get_face_vertices(face_edges):
    face_verts = []
    for edges in face_edges:
        face_verts.append(get_vertices_from_edges(edges))
    # orientations of vertices may not be correct yet                                                                                                                

    orient_order = range(6) # the order in which to fix orientations of faces                                                                                        
    if face_verts[0][0] not in face_verts[1]:
        # make sure the first two faces touch each other, so that all                                                                                                
        # subsequent faces will share an edge with a previously                                                                                                      
        # oriented face                                                                                                                                              
        orient_order[1] = 2
        orient_order[2] = 1

    oriented_edges = set()
    for face_index in orient_order:
        verts = face_verts[face_index]
        edges = zip(verts, verts[-1:] + verts[:-1])

        # make it so that if face A and face B share an edge, they                                                                                                   
        # orient the shared edge in opposite ways                                                                                                                    
        needs_reverse = False
        for a, b in edges:
            if (a, b) in oriented_edges:
                needs_reverse = True
                break
        if needs_reverse:
            verts.reverse()

        edges = zip(verts, verts[-1:] + verts[:-1])
        for a, b in edges:
            oriented_edges.add((a, b))

    return face_verts

print get_face_vertices(FACE_EDGES)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 7, 6, 5], [0, 4, 5, 1], [1, 5, 6, 2], [2, 6, 7, 3], [3, 7, 4, 0]]
```